# firebase.database () multiple instances

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database and I was wondering which is a better pattern  regarding

```
firebase.database()
```

is it considered bad practice to have multiple instances of this. Is it better if I  have a single instance of the database which is exported within the node app. Or is it basically the same thing to create a new instance for every single action creator file.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export default firebase;
```

I have this approach for the firebase app instance and I am unsure if a similar pattern is required for the database instance as well. There weren't any specifications within the [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database) docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call one of the product methods on the `firebase` object that you get from the import, it will give you exactly the same object in return.  So, every time you call `firebase.auth()`, you'll get the same thing back, and every time you call `firebase.database()`, you'll get the same thing.  How you want to manage those instances is completely your preference.

Comment: I was just wondering if there are any downsides to have multiple instances of a database instance

Comment: My answer is saying that there are not actually multiple instances. There is one instance, and you're holding a reference to it in multiple places.  Each reference takes a few bytes.